# How to rotate player towards mouse position with a moving camera using cinemachine and input system? Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I already know how to rotate the player based on the mouse position, there are tons of tutorials about that. **However, every time I need the camera to move (normally using cinemachine) I get a supper jittery movement and the way the player faces the mouse changes.** This is the code I used as for now, yet this is a problem I've had for a long time and can't seem to find anyone asking about it.

**I'm using the new Input system, though if needed I can use the old one and using the 2D camera in cinemachine**

```
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if(angle != 0)
        {
            savedAngle = angle;
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, savedAngle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Mathf.SmoothDamp() to make sure the angle doesn't change too much at once.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html

something like this (**assuming this code is running in `Update()`/`FixedUpdate()`/`LateUpdate()`**) :

```
// class member variables
[SerializeField] private float _smoothTime = 0.3f;
private float _velocity = 0.0f;
...
...
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
if(angle != 0)
{
    savedAngle = Mathf.SmoothDamp(savedAngle, angle, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
}
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, savedAngle);
```

Comment: I will edit my answer later to add code sample.

Comment: @Dread I edited my answer with a code sample, check it out.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out and I will talk back to you